# Updating local variables inside a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm learning python and about to complete a program to run a rock, paper, scissors game between two players for three rounds and update player scores at the end of each round and display it on screen:

```
import random
"""This program plays a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors between two Players,
and reports both Player's scores each round."""

moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

"""#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
"""This program plays a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors between two Players,
and reports both Player's scores each round."""

moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

"""The Player class is the parent class for all of the Players
in this game"""


class Player:
    def move(self):
        return 'rock'

    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
        pass


def beats(one, two):
    return ((one == 'rock' and two == 'scissors') or
            (one == 'scissors' and two == 'paper') or
            (one == 'paper' and two == 'rock'))


class RandomPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        return random.choice(moves)

class Game:

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    def keep_p1_score(self, p1_Score):
        return p1_Score

    def play_round(self):
        move1 = self.p1.move()
        move2 = self.p2.move()
        p1_Score = 0
        p2_Score = 0
        print(f"Player One played: {move1}  Player Two played: {move2}")
        if beats(move1, move2) == True:
            print('**Player One wins**')
            p1_Score += 1
        elif beats(move2, move1) == True:
            print('**Player Two wins**')
            p2_Score += 1
        else:
            print('**TIE**')
        print(f'Score: Player One: {p1_Score} Player Two: {p2_Score}')
        self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
        self.p2.learn(move2, move1)

    def play_game(self):
        print("Game start!")
        for round in range(3):
            print(f"Round {round + 1}:")
            self.play_round()
        print("Game over!")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game(RandomPlayer(), RandomPlayer())
    game.play_game()
```

The problem is when I run the code it doesn't update players scores. As you can see in this picture of the output even though player two won rounds two and three, his score at the end of run three is still 1 instead of 2. I know that's because for each iteration of `play_round` function in the for loop inside the `play_game` function the values of `p1_score` and `p2_score` resets to zero but I do not know how to stop that from happening. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. 
[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9nVr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `p1_Score` and `p2_Score` are *local* variables in `play_round`. So every time you call this function, you get a *new* instance of these variables. Moreover, you *always* set

```
p1_Score = 0
p2_Score = 0
```

in `play_round`. So at the end of the function no score will ever be larger than 1.

To rememdy this, use `self.p1_Score` and `self.p2_Score` to make these variables instance variables and also move the 0-initialization into the `__init__` function of the game class. Alternatively, make the score a class variable of the `Player` class.